# Programming a usable window using C

Tags: c, user-interface, window

So being new to the C language i want to program a simple window or GUI. are there any good web pages or books i could get to learn how to do this? I've searched around on the net and haven't come up with anything! or if someone could send me on the right track like what to #include and maybe some important commands that i will need that would be awesome! thanks!

Comment: Start with google : "C windows gui" or "C linux gui". We will only be able to help you if you ask *specific* questions about problems you may encounter while programming.

Comment: You don't want to write applications in C. There's a reason it's labeled a system programming language and not one for application development. It's not even remotely fun.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that programming GUI in C today is not exactly a widely accepted option.  (in other words -- nobody writes a new GUI in C today)

Comment: On a side note why does nobody write gui's in c?

Comment: You propably know how easy it is to shoot yourself in the foot in C. The advantages that this brings (performance, efficy, being close to the metal, ...) don't matter when you write a GUI. And you really miss the many abstractions you can't have (without building them yourself in a very repetive fashion) because of that when you have to manage a complex GUI, possibly running tasks in the background, *and* solving the actual problem.

Comment: @Zieklecknerizer- A big reason that C-language GUIs aren't commonly done because there aren't a lot of C-language GUI toolkits out there.  Languages like C++ (among others) have many more options available, thus they are more commonly used.  Also, some of the higher-level programming concepts not available in C (classes, advanced inheritance, etc) make GUI development much easier.

Comment: @Zieklecknerizer - The bottom line is that the nature of the C language doesn't lend itself well to some of the demands imposed by GUI programming.  C doesn't make event-driven programming easy to begin with (callbacks are clumsy and the syntax can get ugly), and GUI programming introduces memory management issues out the wazoo.  A small GUI-driven program can easily be an order of magnitude larger than an equivalent console program and significantly more complex.  Say what you will about Java and Swing (many have), you can at least womp up a small applet with a minimum of effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [GTK](http://www.gtk.org).  You didn't say what OS you are using.  GTK is cross platform, but easiest to use on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need a gui toolkit, you can either use one built into your OS (eg the Win32 API on windows) or pick a platform independant one

Qt http://qt.nokia.com/ is probably the most popular full featured one, or you can start with something quicker and easy like http://www.fltk.org/

Comment: Although good recommendations in general, those toolkits are both for C++, not C.